# Transparent Glass looking grey when exported

Tags: texturing, transparency, lighting

Hello everyone I was following a tutorial online on how to make a cup and light it. I've been using blender for a while and I always have this issue of the the output of the render not being fully transparent, it exports as a dim or dark grey object that when placed over a background looks totally off, it happens even if I the environment is very bright bright. Any recommendations on how I can export it and still make it look right. I've already hidden the plane floor used and done most of the transparency settings. [image]

[image]

and here is my setup
https://imgur.com/eUisigb

Comment: alright thank you

Comment: could you please pack the images and share again?

Comment: hi sorry, i don't understand what pack images are. what do you mean

Comment: Go into File > External Data > Pack Resources, save again, if the file is too heavy for the platform, use another one and share the link

Comment: @moonboots ive done that now, kindly please recheck, thank you

Comment: i noticed that earlier and used plain white, render results where still grey and dull, same with hdri

Comment: OK I've edited, please see if it fixes your problem

Comment: ohh i think im getting the hang of it, please how can i use this is photoshop without converting to 16bit, because it seems like it looses so lights and reflections when i do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the white of your *ColorRamp* is pure white:

[image]

Also you need to save as an EXR image if you want the reflection on transparent background, not PNG.Then you'll be able to convert back to PNG in an image editor (Photoshop, Krita...):

[image]

Comment: woah looks better, i actually tried using EXR before but didn't understand it. what application did you use to open the EXR, i'm using photoshop. and also did you make changes to the materials aswell

Comment: thanks! alright let me work on it, ill get back to you